# Enter / return button not submitting form in IE

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following on a page as well as other forms but this, or any of the others, simply do not submit using the Enter key whereas they do in Firefox - I am at a loss to understand why? I put the hidden submit in there to make it work with firefox.

I am using onclick as the submit button graphic is in a class with background sprite image.

Is there a way to make this happen?

```
<form action="/userlogin.html" method=post name="LOGform"><h1>Member Sign In</h1>

<fieldset id="inputs">
<div class="form_row">

<div class="form_row_name"><label>Email</label></div>
<div class="form_row_input"><input id="username" type="username" name="username" value="" style="width:60%;" placeholder="Your Email Address"></div>
</div>  

<div class="form_row">

<div class="form_row_name"><label>Password</label></div>
<div class="form_row_input"><input id="password" type="password" name="password" value='' style="width:60%;" placeholder="Your Account Password"></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="actions">
<div><div style="float:left; width:35%">
<a onclick="document.forms['LOGform'].submit(); return false;" class="button" href="javascript:;">Sign In</a></div>

<input type="submit" style="display:none"/>
<input type="hidden" name="LOGON" value="logon">
<input type="hidden" name="from" value="">

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an image for your submit button you could just use an image input type instead of a submit button, ie:

```
<input type="image" src="/mybuttonGraphic.gif" />
```

This will work on hitting enter across browsers.

Comment: Can't do that - the image is a background, the button text is overwritten on top of it